# bought the Buffalo 300nh router, can I setup dd-wrt before disabling my other wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I am renting a wireless router with cable connection from my local ISP.

I want to setup my Buffalo 300nh router with dd-wrt before returning the ISP's wireless router.

Is this possible for me to do?  i.e. can I connect directly to the 300nh, wipeout the existing firmware with dd-wrt and make sure everything is working before returning the ISP's router?

Is it possible to test it live by connecting a cable from the ISP router to the 300nh for internet connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, totally. If your router has the login credentials for your ISP, then you won't be able to test that without unplugging the ISP router, but everything else should be testable.